# Is it possible to change Timer Tick in the middle of running

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have application that execute some task via `Timer` every new minutes and i want to add the option to make this task changeable using user input in the middle of application running.
if for example my `Timer.Tick` is set to 1 minute and changed into 1 hour, `Timer.Tick` property will update ir i need to restart my application ?

Comment: timer.tick = 1 hour? that works, it would be faster if yo just try it, tick is in miliseconds just do the convertion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran this in LINQPad and it 'ticks' every second after I change the interval, meaning it looks like it respects your change to the interval property immediately.

```
void Main()
{
    var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Interval = 50000;
    timer.Start();

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    timer.Interval = 1000;
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tick");
}
```

I'm assuming you are using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` based on you referencing the `Tick` event. I also ran the same test using `System.Threading.Timer` and saw the same results.